# csvshuf: a tool to shuffle CSV columns written in Python

Tags: python, random, csv, shuffle

**Edit**: After reading Gareth's answer I have pushed an updated version of the code to [github](https://github.com/pereorga/csvshuf).

I needed to shuffle cells from specific columns in several CSV files. One of the requirements was to be able to do *derangement* (shuffling that leaves no element in its original place), I [read about Sattolo's algorithm](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/218255/149749).

So I started writing `csvshuf` this afternoon. Code was originally based in [csvcut](https://gist.github.com/JoeGermuska/561347). I tried to make it good but I am sure it can be improved as I have little experience programming in Python. I would be grateful if I get some code review.

Code:

```
import csv
import sys
import random
import getopt


# From https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/218255/149749
def shuffle_kfy(items):
    i = len(items) - 1
    while i > 0:
        j = random.randrange(i + 1)  # 0 <= j <= i
        items[j], items[i] = items[i], items[j]
        i = i - 1
    return items

def shuffle_sattolo(items):
    i = len(items)
    while i > 1:
        i = i - 1
        j = random.randrange(i)  # 0 <= j <= i-1
        items[j], items[i] = items[i], items[j]
    return items

def shuffle(items, mode):
    if mode == 'kfy':
        return shuffle_kfy(items)
    if mode == 'sattolo':
        return shuffle_sattolo(items)

    random.shuffle(items)
    return items


opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], "c:C:d:o:q:tks", [])
if args:
    i = open(args[0], 'U')
else:
    i = sys.stdin

delimiter = ','
output_delimiter = ','
cols = None
no_cols = None
quotechar = None
search_mode = ''

if opts:
    opts = dict(opts)
    if '-c' in opts:
        cols = map(int, opts['-c'].split(','))
    elif '-C' in opts:
        no_cols = map(int, opts['-C'].split(','))
    if '-k' in opts:
        search_mode = 'kfy'
    elif '-s' in opts:
        search_mode = 'sattolo'
    if '-t' in opts:
        delimiter = "\t"
    elif '-d' in opts:
        delimiter = opts['-d']
    if '-o' in opts:
        output_delimiter = opts['-o']
    if '-q' in opts:
        quotechar = opts['-q']

if cols and 0 in cols or no_cols and 0 in no_cols:
    print("Invalid column 0. Columns are 1-based")
    exit(1)

reader = csv.reader(i, delimiter=delimiter, quotechar=quotechar)
headers = next(reader)

table = []
for c in range(len(headers)):
    table.append([])

for row in reader:
    for c in range(len(headers)):
        table[c].append(row[c])

if not cols and not no_cols:
    cols = range(len(headers))
elif no_cols:
    cols = list(set(range(len(headers))) - set(no_cols))

for c in cols:
    if c > len(headers):
        print('Invalid column {}. Last column is {}').format(c, len(headers))
        exit(1)
    table[c - 1] = shuffle(table[c - 1], search_mode)

table = zip(*table)

writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout, delimiter=output_delimiter)
writer.writerow(headers)
for row in table:
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Usage:

```
csvshuf -c1 foobar.csv
(shuffles the first column of each row of foobar.csv using Python's shuffle())

svshuf -c2 -k foobar.csv
(shuffles the second column of each row using Knuth-Fischer-Yeats algorithm.)

svshuf -c3 -s foobar.csv
(shuffles the third column of each row using Sattolo's algorithm.)

csvshuf foobar.csv
(shuffles all the columns of foobar.csv)

csvshuf -C1 foobar.csv
(shuffles all the columns but the first of foobar.csv)

head -10 foobar.csv | csvshuf -c 1,3
(shuffles the first and third columns of the first ten lines of foobar.csv)

csvshuf -c1,3 -d "|" foobar.csv
(shuffles the first and third columns of the pipe-delimited foobar.csv)

csvshuf -c 1,3 -t foobar.csv
(shuffles the first and third columns of the tab-delimited foobar.csv if present, the -d option will be ignored.)

csvshuf -c 1,2,3 -d "|" -o , foobar.csv
(shuffles the first three columns of the pipe-delimited foobar.csv; output will be comma-delimited.)

csvshuf -c 1,2,3 -o "|" foobar.csv
(shuffles the first three columns of the comma-delimited foobar.csv; output will be pipe-delimited.)

csvshuf -c 1,2 -d "," -q "|" foobar.csv
(shuffles the first two columns of the comma-delimited, pipe-quoted foobar.csv.)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. There are no docstrings. It's hard to review code when we don't know what it is supposed to do.
2. The various `shuffle` functions both modify their `items` argument and return it. It would be clearer if these functions *either* modified their argument without returning it (like [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle)) or returned a new list without modifying the original (like [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample)). Doing both is redundant and confusing.
3. The shuffle functions can be simplified using [`reversed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) and [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#range):

   ```
   def shuffle_sattolo(items):
       """Shuffle items in place using Sattolo's algorithm."""
       _randrange = random.randrange
       for i in reversed(range(1, len(items))):
           j = _randrange(i)  # 0 <= j < i
           items[j], items[i] = items[i], items[j]
   ```

   Note that I've cached `random.randrange` in a local variable. This is to avoid having to look it up again each time around the loop.
4. The `shuffle_kfy` function is redundant because [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) already implements the [Fisher–Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).
5. Using a string argument to select a mode of operation is error-prone. If you mistyped the string, for example `shuffle(items, 'satolo')`, then you would not get an error, it would just silently do the wrong thing.
6. The `shuffle` function is redundant. Instead of assigning a *search mode* while parsing the arguments, assign a *shuffle function*:

   ```
   shuffle = random.shuffle

   # ...

   if '-k' in opts:
       shuffle = shuffle_kfy
   elif '-s' in opts:
       shuffle = shuffle_sattolo
   ```
7. Having code at the top level of a module makes it hard to test — for example, you can't test the `shuffle` function by itself, because you can't import the module without running all the top-level code. It is a good idea to put top-level code into a `main` function and guard it with [`if __name__ == '__main__':`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html).
8. The code processes the command-line options by transforming them into a dictionary and then looking up each valid argument. But this means that there are no error messages for invalid arguments. If you look at the [`getopt` examples in the manual](https://docs.python.org/3/library/getopt.html), you'll see that they do:

   ```
   for o, a in opts:
       if o == '-v':
           # process option
       else:
           # report error
   ```
9. The name `i` is normally used for *index* variables, so it's misleading to use it for an *input file*.
10. Error messages should go to standard error, not standard output:

    ```
    sys.stderr.write("Invalid column 0. Columns are 1-based.\n")
    ```

    This is particularly important here, because this program writes its results to standard output, and so probably the user is redirecting standard output to a file. If you write error messages to standard output, they will go to the file and the user will not see them.
11. It's a better idea to use the [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) module for parsing command-line arguments. With `argparse` the code is more explicit, it automatically emits error messages for invalid arguments, it has various types of built-in argument validation and conversion, and it has built-in support for the `--help` option. Something like this:

    ```
    def column_list(string):
        """Validate and convert comma-separated list of column numbers."""
        try:
            columns = list(map(int, string.split(',')))
        except ValueError as e:
            raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError(*e.args)
        for column in columns:
            if column < 1:
                raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError(
                    "Invalid column {!r}: column numbers start at 1."
                    .format(column))
        return columns

    def main():
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
            description="Shuffle columns in a CSV file")
        parser.add_argument('infile', type=argparse.FileType('r'), nargs='?',
                            default=sys.stdin, help='Input CSV file')
        parser.add_argument('-s', '--sattolo',
                            action='store_const', const=shuffle_sattolo,
                            dest='shuffle', default=random.shuffle,
                            help="Use Sattolo's shuffle.")
        col_group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
        col_group.add_argument('-c', '--columns', type=column_list,
                               help="Comma-separated list of columns to include.")
        col_group.add_argument('-C', '--no-columns', type=column_list,
                               help="Comma-separated list of columns to exclude.")
        delim_group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
        delim_group.add_argument('-d', '--delimiter', type=str, default=',',
                                 help="Input column delimiter.")
        delim_group.add_argument('-t', '--tabbed', dest='delimiter',
                                 action='store_const', const='\t',
                                 help="Delimit input with tabs.")
        parser.add_argument('-q', '--quotechar', type=str, default='"',
                            help="Quote character.")
        parser.add_argument('-o', '--output-delimiter', type=str, default=',',
                            help="Output column delimiter.")
        args = parser.parse_args()

        reader = csv.reader(args.infile, delimiter=args.delimiter,
                            quotechar=args.quotechar)

        # ... and so on ...
    ```

Comment: Many thanks! I've done most of the changes and uploaded the code in https://github.com/pereorga/csvshuf/blob/master/csvshuf